# Dependent variables inside limits

Tags: limits

Is it OK to put dependent variables of the bound variable inside limits, instead of functions of the bound variable? For example, in the context of the first principle of differentiation, could one write: $$f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$ provided that $\Delta y = f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$?

Edit: another simpler example would be 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \ y = 1 $$
Where $y = \frac{\sin x}{x}$

Comment: Yes, of course.  Saying that y= f(x), some function of x, is just saying that "y" is another name for f(x).  Anywhere that f(x) can be used, y can be used.

Comment: But isn't bound variables forbidden outside the operator? That means, we shouldn't be able to define $y$ in terms of $x$ outside of the limit expression, as long as $x$ is bounded by the limit operator.

Comment: You used the phrase "bound variable" in your first post but I see no "bound variables" in this.

Comment: If we say $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x)$, then $x$ is the bound variable